# HIVE. Loading CSV headered with dynamic columns

Tags: hadoop, hive

Could I load CSV file with headers into hive table it **file** has dynamic number of columns ?
For example;
I created external table
`CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE art_stat(art sting, rate1 string, rate2 string, prop1 string,prop2 string)` ...

I have CSV files with headers
File1 (has only three columnth):

```
ART,RATE1,PROP2
apple,109,red
apple,90,green
grape,10,red
......
```

File2 (has only props columnth):

```
ART,PROP1,PROP2 
candy,109,black
cooky,90,brown
grape,10,red
......
```

How can I load this files into my table using standart hive tools?

I have one idea is creating of bash script which creates temp table with current columns and then load data from temp table to target table

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the decision. Is using map type for dynamic columns.
create table `art_data(art string, D map<string,string>)`. I made custom SerDe library to pass my csv files with dynamic format, to the constant format with `map` column

Comment: Please can you share an example of your SerDe library usage